# Python: Integrate user agent in app.acquire_token_by_username_password

Tags: python, azure-ad-msal

I'm currently trying to integrate proxy + user-agent with MSAL library.

Currently, this code is working perfectly:

```
app.acquire_token_by_username_password(
                    config["username"], config["password"], scopes=config["scope"], proxies=my_proxy)
```

However, when I try to add something like:

```
app.acquire_token_by_username_password(
                    config["username"], config["password"], scopes=config["scope"], proxies=my_proxy, headers = {'User-agent': 'My user-agent'})
```

I obtain:

```
obtain_token_by_username_password() got multiple values for keyword argument 'headers'
```

Has someone an idea on how to solve that problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered in the MSAL Python's github repo https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/issues/189

The suggestion was to use `app_name` parameter instead.